# Is magento a right platform for my requirement?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I am having difficulty to decide if Magento CE(either 1.9.x, or 2.x) is capable of satisfying below scenario:

It is travel agency website, where customer can choose their tour package for different destination and do a checkout.

I believe Magento can handle above scenario like a charm. **However**, The agency requires another portal for their agent partners where they can sign up as an Agent and the admin approves their registration.

The agent will view the packages at the different pricing and can order and checkout.

They can also view their previous bookings or download the invoices for it. The invoice will have the Agent company logo (which they provided during their registration) and not the store logo.

I believe this is not possible using Magento out of the box, are there any extension available to help me to do what I want? Or I try considering a solution different than Magento?

Comment: you should go for wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Magento offers customer groups that can be used for setting different price rules. So you can setup "Agent" custom group (or several for each Agent) and use that group/groups for managing prices per Agent. You as an administrator can assign new customers to the Agent group.

Previous purchuases/booknings together with invoices are out of the box. As far as I rembember on the frontend side invoice is a html page served in a way that triggers browser print screen. If you want to customize that it is not big problem for a fronted developer. You will need only someone to add invoice logo for agent customer account settings. This should not be a big task for a experienced developer. If you do not want to go that way you could use some extension that adds avatar to the customer account and use it in the invoice template.

Your actual concern should not be about logo on agent invoices but the way to structure your products. Since they are tours they might have different options sometimes with many possibilities of customizing them. You should look into the way given platform offers to setup your products. Try to define how each tour package looks like, how would you like it to be configurable from the customer side and then look which platform allows for such settings.